# Executing a local shell function on a remote host over ssh using Python

Tags: python, ksh

My `.profile` defines a function

```
myps () {
        ps -aef|egrep "a|b"|egrep -v "c\-"
}
```

I'd like to execute it from my python script

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("ssh user@box \"$(typeset -f); myps\"", shell=True)
```

Getting an error back

```
bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
bash: -c: line 0: `; myps'
```

Escaping ; results in

```
bash: ;: command not found
```

Comment: What does the normal ssh command look like (eg. `ssh user@box ....`)?

Comment: Thank you for asking. Normal command looks like `ssh user@box "$(typeset -f); myps"`. It works perfectly fine.

Comment: you could try
`subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/ssh","user@box","$(typeset -f);myps"])` ?

Comment: @JoranBeasley, that won't actually work -- only the first array element is parsed as shell script content, so the `$(typeset -f)` won't run locally (to export local shell functions).

Comment: @Jam, ...btw, part of the problem here is that your `.profile` isn't executed in noninteractive shells, so the function definition won't actually be loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using this.

```
import subprocess
import sys
import re

HOST = "user@" + box
COMMAND = 'my long command with many many flags in single quotes'

ssh = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "%s" % HOST, COMMAND],
                       shell=False,
                       stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                       stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
result = ssh.stdout.readlines()
```

Comment: This doesn't run a local shell function on the remote host at all. Where in the code does it retrieve the definition of a shell function? Where does it pass that function to the remote host? It's fine code -- there's nothing intrinsically wrong with it -- but it doesn't answer the question you explicitly asked.

Answer (score 1):

```
script='''
. ~/.profile # load local function definitions so typeset -f can emit them
ssh user@box ksh -s <<EOF
$(typeset -f)
myps
EOF
'''

import subprocess
subprocess.call(['ksh', '-c', script]) # no shell=True
```

---

There are a few pertinent items here:

- The dotfile defining this function needs to be locally invoked *before* you run `typeset -f` to dump the function's definition over the wire. By default, a noninteractive shell does not run the majority of dotfiles (any specified by the `ENV` environment variable is an exception).

  In the given example, this is served by the `. ~/profile` command within the script.
- The shell needs to be one supporting `typeset`, so it has to be `bash` or `ksh`, not `sh` (as used by `script=True` by default), which may be provided by `ash` or `dash`, lacking this feature.

  In the given example, this is served by passing `['ksh', '-c']` is the first two arguments to the argv array.
- `typeset` needs to be run locally, so it can't be in an argv position other than the first with `script=True`. (To provide an example: `subprocess.Popen(['''printf '%s\n' "$@"''', 'This is just literal data!', '$(touch /tmp/this-is-not-executed)'], shell=True)` evaluates only `printf '%s\n' "$@"` as a shell script; `This is just literal data!` and `$(touch /tmp/this-is-not-executed)` are passed as literal data, so no file named `/tmp/this-is-not-executed` is created).

  In the given example, this is mooted by *not using* `script=True`.
- Explicitly invoking `ksh -s` (or `bash -s`, as appropriate) ensures that the shell evaluating your function definitions matches the shell you *wrote* those functions against, rather than passing them to `sh -c`, as would happen otherwise.

  In the given example, this is served by `ssh user@box ksh -s` inside the script.

Answer (score 0):

The original command was not interpreting the `;` before `myps` properly. Using `sh -c` fixes that, but... ( please see Charles Duffy comments below ).

Using a combination of single/double quotes sometimes makes the syntax easier to read and less prone to mistakes. With that in mind, a safe way to run the command ( provided the functions in `.profile` are actually accessible in the shell started by the subprocess.Popen object ):

```
subprocess.call('ssh user@box "$(typeset -f); myps"', shell=True),
```

An alternative ( less safe ) method would be to use `sh -c` for the subshell command:

```
subprocess.call('ssh user@box "sh -c $(echo typeset -f); myps"', shell=True) 
# myps is treated as a command
```

This seemingly returned the same result:

```
subprocess.call('ssh user@box "sh -c typeset -f; myps"', shell=True)
```

There are definitely alternative methods for accomplishing these type of tasks, however, this might give you an idea of what the issue was with the original command.

Comment: ...so, the three suggestions really each call for individual commentary.

Comment: in `sh -c echo $(typeset -f); myps`, the first command is `sh -c echo`, with extra arguments generated via the output to `typeset` (if any) filling out `$0`, `$1`, etc. when `echo` is invoked -- but, since you didn't run, say, `sh -c 'echo "$0" "$@"'`, they're effectively ignored, since that script (containing only an `echo` command) doesn't actually read its argument list.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: When i ran the command typeset showed all the `env` variables, as well as the command following it (eg. `BASH_ARGV=([0]="myps")`. So perhaps maybe I'm not understanding some aspect?

Comment: With the `-f` argument, `typeset` dumps function definitions -- the goal here is to ensure that defined functions are accessible to the remote shell.

Comment: ...however, as I describe in my answer, the OP isn't actually ensuring that the subprocess created with `subprocess.call()` is actually *picking up* the functions defined in the local dotfiles.

Comment: Okay, that's what it's doing for sure. The first command shown dumps the definitions and shows the command as an argument within the output. The second example dumps the defs then runs the command afterward (both output). The third one doesn't show the defs, ( just a `1` ), and the runs the command.

Comment: jumping back to my prior comment, try running `sh -c echo hello world`; unlike `sh -c "echo hello world"`, you'll see that it emits only an empty line. Your third suggestion may succeed in defining functions *other than the first* (if there are newlines between them), but it's going to be skipping any functions that became additional arguments to `sh -c echo` by virtue of being in the first line of output from `typeset`.

Comment: ...which is to say that the `echo` is actively harmful. And so is the `sh -c`, for that matter -- the remote shell invoked by `ssh` will *already* be `sh`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Since `echo` and `sh -c` are harmful ( which is somewhat unnerving ) what's the preferred alternative in this situation. I definitely don't want to show an example that is potentially bad in practice ( ponders delete key ). I'm upvoting your answer regardless, since it clearly is not using either!

Comment: `subprocess.call('ssh user@box "$(typeset -f); myps"', shell=True)`, **if** the functions that the OP wants are actually accessible in the shell started by the `subprocess.Popen` object. In my answer, I'm ensuring that my locally sourcing the dotfiles, but if the local `/bin/sh` is provided by bash (rather than being dash or such), and the OP calls `export -f myps` in a parent-process bash instance before this script is invoked, then it could potentially work even without that effort.